# How do I call RPGLE program from a DB2 trigger?

Tags: triggers, db2, rpgle

I have a table `IMGMAST`, on insert, I'd like to call RPGLE program  `IMGCRT` to process the inserted record.

Program takes in 1 Char(12) parameter (id of the table)

Here is what I got so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PROCESS_NEW_IMG
AFTER INSERT IN IMGMAST
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_ROW
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ATOMIC
  CALL IMGCRT(NEW_ROW.ID)
END
```

However I cannot create the trigger as it says it cannot find the `IMGCRT` program. I tried adding library to it and still can't find it.

Do I need to wrap the call in `CREATE PROCEDURE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to define an external SQL stored procedure that points to the the RPG...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IMGCRT (IN ID INTEGER)
LANGUAGE RPGLE
PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL
FENCED
MODIFIES SQL DATA
EXTERNAL IMGCRT
PROGRAM TYPE MAIN
```